# How to make fields optional in Kotlin serialization in using it in retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an API which its response is kind of dynamic. I mean sometimes it return a Jason object with "token" value, and sometimes it returns with "message" value. For handling this scenario I decided to have both field in my data class like below:

```
data class response {
   val message:String;
   val token:String;
}
```

Now I want to make both fields optional in Kotlin serialization. I mean, I want to tell Kotlin serialization that if you couldn't find token in response JSON it's ok to ignore it.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Kotlin properties with default values are automatically optional.
All I need to do is this:

```
data class response {
   val message: String = "";
   val token: String = "";
}
```